# In which jquery version does outerHTML method exist

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried this in my javascript and it worked without additional plugin

```
var2 = $('.my_div')[0].outerHTML;
```

But i could not find it in official documentation . Where can i find more information about that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.outerHTML)** is a native JavaScript DOM object property. You can read about it in **MDN**:

> *https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.outerHTML*
>
> The outerHTML attribute of the element DOM interface gets the
>   serialized HTML fragment describing the element including its
>   descendants. It can be set to replace the element with nodes parsed
>   from the given string.

Making `$('.my_div')[0]` you **[get](http://api.jquery.com/get/)** the DOM object from jQuery object.

Comment: Why i need to use `[0]` in front of selector. and also can it only applied to div tag only or all tags

Comment: `[0]` (or `.get(0)`) returns the DOM element (the first one in the jQuery collection). And outerHTML is available for all DOM elements (see doc).

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an outerHTML function in standard jQuery.

If what you want is use the standard DOM parameter, see VisioN's answer.

If what you try to do is to set the outerHTML of a jQuery element, in the same way you use the jQuery `html` function, you might use this plugin : [jQuery: outerHTML](http://www.yelotofu.com/2008/08/jquery-outerhtml/)

```
jQuery.fn.outerHTML = function(s) {
return (s)
? this.before(s).remove()
: jQuery("&lt;p&gt;").append(this.eq(0).clone()).html();
}
```

This enables

```
 $('.my_div').outerHTML("<div class=a>new content</div>");
```

Comment: I don't want to use plugins. i don't know why jquery cant have such a simple function in its core

Comment: Which function ? Setting outerHTML : it's rarely needed. Getting outerHTML : it's available in vanilla JS so jQuery has no reason to implement it.